# Nested glCallList in OpenGL c++

Tags: c++, opengl

I am currently trying to program Pacman in C++ using OpenGL. I am currently trying to create a display list to draw the maze. My thoughts were to create a square tile and then simply display said tile if `matrix` indicates a wall segment at some position. My code for this is:

```
const unsigned int FREE = 0;
const unsigned int WALL = 1;
const unsigned int GHOST_WALL = 2;

const unsigned int matrix[22][19] = {
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
    {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1},
    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
};

GLuint tile_handle = 0;
GLuint maze_handle = 0;

/*
 * Initialize maze by precompiling its components
 */
void maze_init() {
    // request a single display list handle for the tile
    tile_handle = glGenLists(1);

    glNewList(tile_handle, GL_COMPILE);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0.7f);  // Blue
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex2i(0,0);
            glVertex2i(1,0);
            glVertex2i(1,1);
            glVertex2i(0,1);
        glEnd();
    glEndList();


    // request a single display list handle for the entire maze
    maze_handle = glGenLists(1);

    glNewList(maze_handle, GL_COMPILE);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0.7f);  // Blue
        for(int row = 0; row < 22; row--) {
            for(int col = 0; col < 19; col++) {
                if(matrix[21-row][col] == WALL) {
                    glPushMatrix();
                        glScaled(30, 30, 1);
                        glTranslated(col, row, 0);
                        glCallList(tile_handle);
                    glPopMatrix();
                }
            }
        }
    glEndList();
}
```

I then use `maze_init()` in my main initialisation method and use the call `glCallList(maze_handle);` in my main display function. This compiles fine but when I try to run it, it gives me a `Bus error: 10` error.

Now I tried the same without the loops in the definition of `glNewList(maze_handle, GL_COMPILE);` and it ran fine. My question is therefore this: why do the loops (or the conditional statement) inside the call list create a bus error?

I tried a simple loop inside `glNewList(maze_handle, GL_COMPILE);` that made calls to DISTINCT display lists and it ran fine. So is the problem here that I make a repeated call to the same display list? For some reason I just can't seem to find the problem here ...

Comment: Display lists and fixed-function pipeline are deprecated for more than 8 years. You should switch to modern OpenGL instead.

Comment: Because you decrement `row` in the loop instead of incrementing it? I sometimes wonder if people look at their code before posting it...

Comment: Wow yeah sorry about that ... Thanks!!